# Debugging of R script

Tags: r

I have a script written on Basic, that get on input CSV-file and compute collision between random splitting of input data. This script is [here](http://pastebin.com/gPvpke5j). I need to reimplement it on R. I've written [such](http://pastebin.com/dF2xHUb0) script. [Here](http://pastebin.com/mceaiuxA) is input data.

But in condition

```
if(nentries==nrows*ncolumns)    
{  
    print("Columns, rows, and entries check; we're good to go.")  
}  
else  
{  
    print("Columns, rows, and entries don't check; please look at your data file to make sure each line has equal no. of entries.")  
}
```

appear error

```
source("path\\to\\script.r")
error in source("path\\to\\script.r") : 
D:\projects\basicToR\target.r:19:1: Unexpected 'else'
18:         }
19: else
    ^
```

Why is the error here? And is there other errors in R file?

**UPDATE**
I've forgotten write in question about error

Error in seq.default(1, firstsofar, 1) : 
   Invalid sign 'by' argument

in fragment of code

```
for (q in seq(1,firstsofar,1)) {
    if( randnum[i]==randnum[q]) {taken="yes"}
}
```

Comment: As for your edit, it's completely unrelated to your original question, so to get an answer you should start a new question. But it sounds like `firstsofar` took a value less than 1, so that the 3rd argument `by=1` that you've given is the wrong sign (positive, not negative) to get the sequence there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons I don't entirely understand, R freaks out when `else` isn't on the same line as the closing curly bracket before it. Try:

```
if(nentries==nrows*ncolumns)    {
     print("Columns, rows, and entries check; we're good to go.")
}else{
     print("Columns, rows, and entries don't check; please look at your data file to make sure each line has equal no. of entries.")
}
```

Comment: It is the REPL -- line-by-line parsing.

Comment: The reason is that R code is run one line at a time, whether you're at the console or not. It's the same reason you can enter  (at the `>` console)
`> 1 +` and then 
`> 2`, 
but not  
`> 1`
`> + 2`

Comment: Thanks, @DirkEddelbuettel and shujaa for the clarification.

Comment: @shujaa Bad example - you totally can do `> 1` and then `> + 2`.  It's not the same as `> 1 +` then `> 2` but you can do it ;)

Comment: @Dason guess I'll use division next time ;)

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite that as

```
if(nentries==nrows*ncolumns)    {
     print("Columns, rows, and entries check; we're good to go.")
}else{
     print("Columns, rows, and entries don't check; please look at your data file to make sure each line has equal no. of entries.")
}
```

You need to have the else on the same line as the closing brace for the 'if'

From the [R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#if)

> The else clause is optional. The statement if(any(x <= 0)) x <- x[x <=
>   0] is valid. When the if statement is not in a block the else, if
>   present, must appear on the same line as the end of statement2.
>   Otherwise the new line at the end of statement2 completes the if and
>   yields a syntactically complete statement that is evaluated. A simple
>   solution is to use a compound statement wrapped in braces, putting the
>   else on the same line as the closing brace that marks the end of the
>   statement.